# Bootstrap: resizing a window if is a mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make a login menu, but I want to do something like this:

**Width:**

Cellphones: 100%
Tablets: 50%
Computers: 25%

I tried to do col-??-value, but It didn't worked well. Any sugestions?

Comment: Do you want to change the width of the menu or of the hole screen?

Comment: Show a html-code you tried to do, pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

Computer: 25% = 12/4 = `col-md-3` (`col-lg-3` is also but it will be computed by default equal to col-md);

tablets: 50% = 12/2 = `col-sm-6`;

cellphones: 100% = 12cells= `col-xs-12`

to center a menu you can add offsets: `col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) as shown below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using bootstrap grid. Just use the columns with different breakpoints to control width of your content:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
</div>
</div>
```